# Forward one port from a PC with no admin rights

Tags: windows-10, port-forwarding

There is this Windows 10 laptop where I have no admin rights and which is connected a) to a Domain and b) to a LAN.

Is it possible to forward one port from this laptop to another PC in the same LAN?

Comment: For basically all OS (you didn't say which one you have), setting up port forwarding requires admin rights. So, no admin rights, no port forwarding. That said, nothing keeps you from setting up some other machine (where you do have admin rights), connecting it to the domain (if you have the credentials), and also connecting it to your LAN.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried already your second proposal. There a) I was very surprised that the Domain instantly gave me full access this way; and b) I know that I'm not supposed to do that. Therefore, I'd rather forward that one port (which is not susceptible to security risks) from the official device than access the entire domain wide open as a barn door with an illicit device.
[Added "Windows 10" as OS in the OP]

Answer (score 1):

It's not as fast as doing it in-kernel, but this can be done without administrative privileges with `socat` and other similar tools:

This command listen on port 5050 and forward all to port 2020:

```
socat tcp-l:5050,fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:2020
```

All credit goes to this post/answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293304/using-netcat-for-port-forwarding#answer-293308

Upstream socat supports Unix operating systems but the socat in Cygwin worked for me, and there is at least one unofficial Windows build: https://github.com/StudioEtrange/socat-windows.

(I don't know whether Windows does its port forwarding in the kernel, I just say so because that's what Linux does.)